# Why does COUNT() show only one row of table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, mysql-5.7

I have the following table `pet` in the database `menagerie`:

```
+--------+-------------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| name   | owner       | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
+--------+-------------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| Tommy  | Salman Khan | Lebre   | NULL | 1999-01-13 | 0000-00-00 |
| Bowser | Diane       | dog     | m    | 1981-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
+--------+-------------+---------+------+------------+------------+
```

Now If I run the following query:

```
select owner, curdate() from pet;
```

I get the following output:

```
+-------------+------------+
| owner       | curdate()  |
+-------------+------------+
| Salman Khan | 2016-09-12 |
| Diane       | 2016-09-12 |
+-------------+------------+
```

The output show all the values of `owner`, and the value returned from `curdate()` in each row.

Now if I run the following query:

```
select owner, count(*) from pet;
```

I get the following output:

```
+-------------+----------+
| owner       | count(*) |
+-------------+----------+
| Salman Khan |        2 |
+-------------+----------+
```

My question is what is the difference between `curdate()` and `count()` function which makes `MySQL` to output the second `owner` *Diane* in the first example?

Comment: @KevinEsche Yes it executes. I've copied the commands and tables from `cmd`.

Comment: You get 1 line cuz ya screwed up with no `group by` :p

Comment: That query is invalid, and should raise an error. (Perhaps newer MySQL versions will?)

Comment: @jarlh I am using the latest version 5.7.

Comment: @jarlh Depends on the value of [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY `](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`COUNT()` is an aggregation function which is usually combined with a `GROUP BY` clause.

`curdate()` is a date function which outputs the current date.

Only MySQL (as far as I know of) allows this syntax without using the `GROUP BY` clause. Since you didn't provide it, `COUNT(*)` will count the total amount of rows in the table , and the `owner` column will be selected randomly/optimizer default/by indexes .

This should be your query :

```
select owner, count(*) 
from pet
group by owner;
```

Which tells the optimizer to count total rows, for **each** owner.

When no group by clause mentioned - the aggregation functions are applied on the entire data of the table.

**EDIT:** A count that will be applied on each row can't be normally done with `COUNT()` and usually used with an analytic function -> `COUNT() OVER(PARTITION...)` which unfortunately doesn't exist in MySQL. Your other option is to make a `JOIN/CORRELATED QUERY` for this additional column.

**Another Edit:** If you want to total count next to each owner, you can use a sub query:

```
SELECT owner,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pet) as cnt
FROM pet
```

Comment: I don't think group by is necessary becasue `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pet;` just counts all the rows from pet. So, like `curdate()` displays same date twice in two rows; `count(*)` should also display total_rows twice in two rows in my second example.

Comment: Yes, only MySQL, so far as I'm aware, has this "damn the torpedoes, I don't care if what you've asked for is nonsense, if I possibly can, I'm going to wildly guess and return a result set rather than give the user a warning" attitude.

Comment: @user31782 - the difference is, you've got an additional column you're asking for in the `select`. MySQL doesn't know whether you intended to group by that column, or wanted an arbitrary value, or you wanted to apply some aggregate to it.

Comment: @user31782 When you are using an aggregation function with no group by - the output will **always** be 1 row .

Comment: How does the subquery work as intended without a `WHERE`? Doesn't look very correlated to me!

Answer (score 7):

This looks exactly like the scenario at the bottom of this page: [MySQL Documentation: 4.3.4.8 Counting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html).

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled, the query is processed by
>   treating all rows as a single group, but the value selected for each
>   named column is indeterminate. The server is free to select the value
>   from any row:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET sql_mode = '';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT owner, COUNT(*) FROM pet;
> +--------+----------+
> | owner  | COUNT(*) |
> +--------+----------+
> | Harold |        8 |
> +--------+----------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

I guess in this case `only_full_group_by` is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Most DBMS systems won't allow a aggregate function like count() with additional columns without a group by; for a reason. The DBMS does not know which columns to group :-).

The solution is to group your query by the owner column, like this:

```
SELECT owner, count(*) FROM pet GROUP BY owner;
```

Answer (score 2):

The last query is invalid for Oracle: ORA-00937: not a single-group function. This means you need a GROUP BY clause. You found a loophole in the MySql implementation. Do not rely on such a query in a production system, in a next version of MySql this might not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Count(*)**  aggregate function it returns only one value and i.e. total number of rows. And **curdate()** function is just provide the system's current date.