# Left join not showing all data while using sum

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 Tables named Product, Stock as follows
Product Table:-

```
Id     Name     Hand
1      A        50
2      B        5
3      C        10
```

Stock Table:-

```
Id    Pid     Qty
1     1       50
```

I want total stock of every product so hand column showing the opening stock.
I tried:

```
select product.id, name, hand, count(qty) 
from product 
left join stock on pid=product.id
```

but it's giving me only the first product detail even i am doing left join

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does COUNT() show only one row of table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444904/why-does-count-show-only-one-row-of-table)

Comment: This is a faq. It's clear that this is going to be a faq Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group by product and use `sum()` instead of `count()`:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.hand, coalesce(sum(qty), 0) totalstock
from product p left join stock s
on s.pid = p.id
group by p.id, p.name, p.hand
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXzxLP15Ujry3s8YpXB4LZ/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name | hand | totalstock |
| --- | ---- | ---- | ---------- |
| 1   | A    | 50   | 50         |
| 2   | B    | 5    | 0          |
| 3   | C    | 10   | 0          |
```